# $f: \Omega \to \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ is measurable if and only if $f_1,f_2$ are measurable

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Following this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278154/is-f-left-omega-1-cdot-right-omega-2-rightarrow-mathbbr-mathca), I was suggested to give a try on this theorem. Could you check if my proof is fine?

---

Let

- $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$, $(\Omega_1, \mathcal F_1)$, and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal F_2)$ be measurable spaces.
- $\mathcal F_1 \otimes \mathcal F_2$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$.
- $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ the projection maps from $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ to $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively.
- $f_1 = \rho_1 \circ f,f_2 = \rho_2 \circ f$ the first and second coordinates of $f$.

Then $f: \Omega \to \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ is measurable if and only if $f_1,f_2$ are measurable.

---

**My attempt:**

By construction of $\mathcal F_1 \otimes \mathcal F_2$, $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are measurable. If $f$ is measurable, then $f_1$ is the composition of $2$ measurable functions and thus is measurable. With similar argument, $f_2$ is measurable. Now we prove the converse direction.

Assume $f_1$ and $f_2$ are measurable. Because $\mathcal F_1 \otimes \mathcal F_2 = \sigma (\mathcal F_1 \times \mathcal F_2)$, we just have to verify that $f^{-1}(A \times B) \in \mathcal F$ for all $A \in \mathcal F_1$ and $B \in \mathcal F_2$. In fact, $$\begin{aligned}f^{-1}(A \times B) &= \{ \omega \mid f(\omega) \in A \times B\} \\ &= \{ \omega \mid f_1(\omega) \in A \text{ and } f_2 (\omega) \in  B\} \\ &= f_1^{-1} (A) \cap f_2^{-1} (B) \in \mathcal F.  \end{aligned}$$

This completes the proof.

---

**Update:** I added a lemma to justify that it's enough to prove $f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2) \subseteq \mathcal{F}$.

*Lemma:* Let $\left(\Omega_{1}, \mathcal{F}\right)$ and $\left(\Omega_{2}, \sigma(\mathcal{C})\right)$ with $C \subseteq \Omega_2$ be two measurable spaces. A function $f: \Omega_{1} \rightarrow \Omega_{2}$ is measurable if $$A \in \mathcal{C} \quad \text {implies} \quad f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}.$$

*Proof:* Consider $\mathcal X = \{A \subseteq \Omega_2 \mid f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}\}$. We have $f^{-1}(A^c) = (f^{-1}(A))^c$ and $f^{-1}(\cup_n A_n)=\cup_n f^{-1}(A_n)$. This means $\mathcal X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega_2$. Moreover, $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal X$. By definition of $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, we obtain $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) \subseteq \mathcal X$. Hence $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Seems okay to me. Is there any particular step you're not sure about?

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the difficult part is showing that, in general,
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G})) = \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})).$$

You seem to be assuming this fact. You have proven that
$$f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2) \subset \mathcal{F}.$$

But you want to prove that
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2)) \subset \mathcal{F}.$$

Comment: How coincidental it is! I proved $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G})) = \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$ 3 months ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182181/prove-that-mathcal-c-subseteq-mathcal-py-implies-sigmaf-1-mat).

Comment: After looking closer to the problem, I found that we don't need $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G})) = \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$. Please see my update.

Comment: @Akira: Yes! You just have to show that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G})) \subset \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$. Your statement that $\mathcal{X} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is wrong, though. What you can conclude is only the opposite inclusion.

Comment: Ah $\mathcal{X} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is a typo. I've deleted it.

Comment: @Akira: Your $\mathcal{X}$ is just the biggest $\sigma$-algebra for which $f$ is measurable. It is probably called: final $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Akira: You also need to remove the conclusion: $\mathcal{X} = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: Ahah The conclusion should be $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) \subseteq \mathcal X$.